# How can I press individual option in actionsheet in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, actionsheet

I am still new to React Native. I have an actionsheet with two options and a cancel option. I am having trouble understanding how to make each option do something different when pressed.

My code:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"
import ActionSheet from 'react-native-actionsheet'
import { View, Text, Pressable } from "react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const ActionSheet = () => {

  let actionSheet = useRef();
  let optionArray = ['Orange', 'Cherry', 'Cancel'];

  const showActionSheet = () => {
    actionSheet.current.show();
  }

  return (
    <View
      <Pressable onPress={showActionSheet}>
        <View>
          <Text>Choose Fruit</Text>
          <Icon name="angle-right" size={15}/>
        </View>
      </Pressable>
      <ActionSheet 
        ref={actionSheet}
        options={optionArray}
        cancelButtonIndex={2}
        onPress={{????}}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**What I'd like to do is navigate to a different screen when an option is pressed**

Would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onPress` function provides an index argument. Thus consider the following code snippet.

```js
const onActionSelect = (index) => {

    if (index === 1) {
      // first action pressed
    } else if (index === 2) {
      // second action pressed
    }
    // and so on
}

<ActionSheet 
        ref={actionSheet}
        options={optionArray}
        cancelButtonIndex={2}
        onPress={onActionSelect}
/>
```